# Fast I/O when working with multiple files

Tags: python, linux, bash, performance, io

I have two input files and I want to mix them and output the result into a third files. In the following I will use a toy example to explain the format of the files and the desired output. Each file contain 4-line pattern which is repeated (but contains a different sequence), and I only include single 4-line:

input file 1:

```
@readheader1
ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
...
```

input file 2:

```
@readheader2
AATTAATT
+
FFFFFFFF
...
```

desired ouput:

```
@readheader1_AATTAATT
ACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACAC
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
...
```

So I want to attach the`first line of every four line from the first file` using an underscore with the `small sequence found in the second line of every four line from the second file`. and I simply output 2n, 3rd, and 4rd line of every four line of the first line, as is, into the output.

I am looking for any script (linux bash, python, c++, etc) that can optimize what I have below:

I wrote this code to do the task, but I found it to be slow (takes more than a day for inputs of size 60 GB and 15 GB); note that the input files are in `fastq.gz` format so I open them using gzip:

```
    ...
    r1_file = gzip.open(r1_file_name, 'r') # input file 1
    i1_file = gzip.open(i1_file_name, 'r') # input file 2
    
    out_file_R1 = gzip.open('_R1_barcoded.fastq.gz', 'wb') # output file

    r1_header = ''
    r1_seq = ''
    r1_orient = ''
    r1_qual = ''
    i1_seq = ''
    cnt = 1 
    with gzip.open(r1_file_name, 'r') as r1_file:
        for r1_line in r1_file:
            if cnt==1:
                r1_header = str.encode(r1_line.decode("ascii").split(" ")[0])
                next(i1_file)
            if cnt==2:
                r1_seq = r1_line
                i1_seq = next(i1_file)
            if cnt==3:
                r1_orient = r1_line
                next(i1_file)
            if cnt==4:
                r1_qual = r1_line
                next(i1_file)
                out_4line = r1_header + b'_' + i1_seq + r1_seq + r1_orient + r1_qual
                out_file_R1.write(out_4line)
                cnt = 0
            cnt += 1
    i1_file.close()
    out_file_R1.close()
```

Then that I have the two outputs made using 2 dataset, I wish to interleave the output files: 4 lines from the first file, 4 lines from the second file, 4 lines from the first, and so on...

Comment: You may want to look into splitting your code into coroutines using asyncio (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). It's probably the most efficient tool given your use case. Threading is anotther option you can try, although you'd waste quite a bit of CPU time if you use threads for this much I/O. You might also want to unzip the files before processing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste` utility (from GNU coreutils) and GNU `sed`:

```
paste file1 file2 |
sed -E 'N; s/\t.*\n([^\t]*)\t(.*)/_\2\n\1/; N; N; s/\t[^\n]*//g' > file.out
```

If files are gzipped then use:

```
paste <(gzip -dc file1.gz) <(gzip -dc file2.gz) |
sed -E 'N; s/\t.*\n([^\t]*)\t(.*)/_\2\n\1/; N; N; s/\t[^\n]*//g' > file.out
```

Note: This assumes no tab characters in file1 and file2

---

**Explanation:** Assume that file1 and file2 contains these lines:
File1:

```
Header1
ACACACACAC
XX
FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

File2:

```
Header2
AATTAATT
YY
GGGGGG
```

After the `paste` command, lines are merged, separated by `TAB`s:

```
Header1\tHeader2
ACACACACAC\tAATTAATT
XX\tYY
FFFFFFFFFFFF\tGGGGGG
```

The `\t` above denotes a tab character. These lines are fed to `sed`. `sed` reads the first line, the pattern space becomes

```
Header1\tHeader2
```

The `N` command adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line (`ACACACACAC\tAATTAATT`) of input to the pattern space. Pattern space becomes

```
Header1\tHeader2\nACACACACAC\tAATTAATT
```

and is matched against regex `\t.*\n([^\t]*)\t(.*)` as denoted below.

```
Header1\tHeader2\nACACACACAC\tAATTAATT
       ||^^^^^^^||^^^^^^^^^^||^^^^^^^^
       \t   .*  \n ([^\t]*) \t  (.*)
       ||       ||    \1    ||   \2
```

The `\n` denotes a newline character. Then the matching part is replaced with `_\2\n\1` by the `s/\t.*\n([^\t]*)\t(.*)/_\2\n\1/` command. Pattern space becomes

```
Header1_AATTAATT\nACACACACAC
```

The two `N` commands read the next two lines. Now pattern space is

```
Header1_AATTAATT\nACACACACAC\nXX\tYY\nFFFFFFFFFFFF\tGGGGGG
```

The `s/\t[^\n]*//g` command removes *all* parts between a TAB (inclusive) and newline (exclusive). After this operation the final pattern space is

```
Header1_AATTAATT\nACACACACAC\nXX\nFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

which is printed out as

```
Header1_AATTAATT
ACACACACAC
XX
FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Thank you so much; can you please add an explanation on how it works? like how you access each record using the regex command?

Comment: @ameerosein Added an explanation.